# Proper way to associate 3 objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 controllers in my app (relevant to this question):

- Employee
- Quiz
- Score

When an Employee takes a quiz, I need to be able to record their score so that it associates the `Quiz` taken, with the `Employee` that took the quiz, and the `Score` they achieved. Currently this is how I have the models setup:

**score_assignment.rb**

```
class ScoreAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :score
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :quiz
end
```

**employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :score_assignments
  has_many :quizzes, :through => :score_assignments
  has_many :scores,  :through => :score_assignments
end
```

**quiz.rb**

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :score_assignments
    has_many :scores, :through => :score_assignments
    has_many :employees, :through => :score_assignments
end
```

**score.rb**

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :score_assignments
    has_many :quizzes,   :through => :score_assignments
    has_many :employees, :through => :score_assignments
end
```

My first qualm with this (aside from being unsure how to actually add the score to all models simultaneously - which I will get into in the next section) is that a score should not have many employees, quizzes, or employees. While an employee will take several quizzes and accumulate a score for each quiz he takes, a score will only ever be assigned to one quiz and one employee. I was unable, however, to get the `has_one` attribute to work with score, when leaving `has_many` on the other models.

**First question:**

Is this setup correctly? (or is there a better way to do this)

**Second question:**

If this is setup correctly, how do I go about adding a score across all 3 models at once? Here are a few things I have tried in the console that I don't think worked:

```
s = Score.new(percentile: 99)
q = Quiz.first
e = Employee.first    
q.scores << s
e.scores << s
```

**Extra info - the DB migrations, in case they help:**

```
class CreateQuizzes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quizzes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :code
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scores do |t|
      t.integer :percentile

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateScoreAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :score_assignments do |t|
      t.integer :quiz_id
      t.integer :employee_id
      t.integer :score_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :score_assignments, :quiz_id
    add_index :score_assignments, :employee_id
    add_index :score_assignments, :score_id
  end

  def down
    drop_table :score_assignments
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the scores exist in their own table seems like madness, especially considering they're just a percentage. Why not have one table that links quizzes, employees together, that has an additional column for the percentage?

```
create_table :scores do |t|
  t.integer :quiz_id
  t.integer :customer_id
  t.integer :percentile
end
```

Then you would associate like this:

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
  has_many :quizzes, :through => :scores
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
  has_many :employees, :through => :scores
end
```

To get a score for an employee for a quiz:

```
quiz.scores.where(:employee_id => employee.id).first.percentile
```

To create a new score:

```
quiz.scores.create(:employee_id => employee.id, :percentile => 99)
```

Comment: I was WAY overcomplicating this. Thank you.

Comment: One more question: is there anything I can add to the scores model to allow me to find employees like this: `score.employee.name` rather than: `Employee.find(score.employee_id).name`. Right now I get this error: `undefined method `employee' for #<Score:0x007f9efee7ea10>`